# Setting state of button inside mapped DIV and only having the state effect the button inside that DIV

Tags: reactjs

```
  .map((value, index) => (
            <div
              className="cardControl"
              id={value.titles}
              style={{
                width: "700px",
                minHeight: "325px",
                border: "1px solid white",
                backgroundColor: "RGB(67, 80, 88, 0.9)",
                color: "white",
                display: props.display,
              }}
            >
```

So I am mapping an array to create div's to display the results in the DIV. Then inside these DIVs I have this button below

````
   <Button
                  id="favButton"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#D4AF37",
                    height: 40,
                    width: 190,
                    color: "white",
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={() => favPressed(value)}
                >
                  {favButtonText}
                </Button>
    ```
````

and then once this button is clicked I am changing the state of favButtonText via this function

```
 let favPressed = (value) => {
    setfavButtonText(<Spinner size="sm" color="danger" />);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setfavButtonText("Favorite Listing");
    }, 1000);
```

Now the issue is, obviously because I am using the same state for all the buttons, when 1 button is pressed, the state is changed for every button in every div in the map.

What I am trying to do is make it to where when the button is pressed in 1 DIV, only that button in that mapped DIV changes state. However, I am unsure how to handle this.

I basically have a list of results which is the mapped divs, and have it setup where they can save a result via pressing the button, and I want to be able to change the button text on the specific result when they press the button in that specific DIV instead of all of them. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction for this and hopefully I worded this question right lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the logic for `setfavButtonText` and `favPressed` into another component, e.g. `<FavButton />`

This way, `setfavButtonText` won't be shared across the list of fav buttons.